# Ver 14.04 LTS on flash drive

Tags: 14.04

I've put the OS on a flash drive to use on an older Win7 machine that has crashed with damaged partition. I want to recover data from the HD, but can't find the access to that HD from the desktop. Where should I look?

Comment: File browser would be a good start. Partitions are usually displayed in the left side panel of the file browser window.

Comment: I am able to open the Disks page to see the partitions, Assessment says "disk is OK, 567 bad sectors". Partition type is NTFS, contents unknown. Where do I see the files?

Answer (score 1):

It is always easier to use a specialised tool. TestDisk is effective in doing so and there are live cd version available which you can load into an USB stick to boot.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: Can this be run from the flashdrive as well? Or should I load the Linux to the faulty HD and then run TestDisk from the flash?

Comment: Yes, you can as long as your pc support usb booting.